POWERSHELL Forms: How to change button colors (fore- and backColor) on mouseover
I'm on WINDOWS 10 and POWERSHELL 7.4.3.
I want to change the colors (fore- and backColor) of a button-control when the mouse hovers/leaves the button. Here is an excerpt of the button-control-settings:
$MyButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$MyButton.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$MyButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Roboto", 12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point, 0)
$MyButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5, 112)
$MyButton.Name = "MyButton"
$MyButton.Text = "My button"
$MyButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150, 40)

I tried adding
$MyButton.Add_MouseHover({$MyButton.Color = [System.Drawing.Color]::Orange})

to change the foreColor but the color does not change when the mouse hovers the button.
Any suggestions?
Peace

The Color property doesn't exist. You're referring to the BackColor and ForeColor properties. If you want these colors to change when the Mouse pointer enters and leaves the premises, subscribe to the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events, and the Enter end Leave events, in case the Control(s) should change color also when they get focus (the former events should raise the latter, in this case) -- You may want to store the original colors (if not inherited from the parent Form a default)

Instead of MouseHover, use events MouseEnter and MouseLeave
$DemoForm = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new()

$MyButton           = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]::new()
$MyButton.FlatStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle]::Flat
$MyButton.Font      = [System.Drawing.Font]::new('Roboto', 12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Point, 0)
$MyButton.Location  = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(55, 112)
$MyButton.Size      = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(150, 40)
$MyButton.Name      = "MyButton"
$MyButton.Text      = "My button"

$MyButton.Add_MouseEnter({
    $this.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Orange
    $this.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::CadetBlue
})

$MyButton.Add_MouseLeave({
    $this.ForeColor = $DemoForm.ForeColor
    $this.BackColor = $DemoForm.BackColor
})

$DemoForm.Controls.Add($MyButton)

$DemoForm.ShowDialog()

# don't forget to remove the form from memory when all done
$DemoForm.Dispose()



Thank you so much. Works like a charm. I searched the internet for hours and did not find any working example. This is a pretty cool piece of code. Thank you again.
